# Cakephp 3 Auth Component password field with MD5

Tags: md5, cakephp-3.0

I am using cakephp 3 and their auth component .. everything is working fine but i want to match my password while login using **md5** instead of default hashing password logic cakephp 3 uses ... what should i do to implement this feature .. here below is my **AppController.php** file what i have done so far ..

**AppController.php**

```
 public function initialize()
    {
        parent::initialize();

        $this->loadComponent('RequestHandler');
        $this->loadComponent('Flash');

        $this->loadComponent('Auth', [
            'loginRedirect' => [
                'controller' => 'Users',
                'action' => 'dashboard'
            ],
            'logoutRedirect' => [
                'controller' => 'Users',
                'action' => 'login'                
            ],
            'loginAction' => [
                'controller' => 'Users',
                'action' => 'login'
            ],            
             'authenticate' => [
                'Form' => [
                    'userModel' => 'Users', 
                    'fields' => [
                        'username' => 'user_email',
                        'password' => 'user_password'
                    ]
                ]
            ],
            'storage' => 'Session',
            'unauthorizedRedirect' => false,            
        ]);
    }
```

as i mentioned above, everything is working fine, i am able to login successfully with default hashing method which cakephp 3 provides, but i just want to exclude this hashing method and need to check using **md5** .. how can i do this ?

Can someone guide me or help me please ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok .. guys .. eventually i have found out the solution and here below is what i have come up with .. so if anybody stuck or want similar feature, they can follow this thing to accomplish this ..

Go here http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/controllers/components/authentication.html#creating-custom-password-hasher-classes there they are saying to create a new file which you need to follow and need to create.

Then in your **Auth Component** make sure you add below line

```
'Form' => [
                'passwordHasher' => [
                    'className' => 'Legacy',
                ]
            ]
```

This is working for me, i hope it helps someone .. Thank you guys.

Comment: I would _highly_! recommend that you [**migrate the passwords**](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/controllers/components/authentication.html#changing-hashing-algorithms) to a more secure hashing method!

Comment: yea .. actually i would like to follow the same hashing password which cakephp provides which is actually more secured but i just wanted to learn at the same time how we can change this feature with **md5** or **sha1** for that matter.